# Not Null in "count" or "find" function in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm trying to find the not null elements in a database

```
@genus_counts = Table.count(:all, :conditions=> {:col1 => params[:gm], :col2 => nil}, :without => {:col3 => nil})
```

It's not recognising "without" function. I am in doubt to apply it as array value.

```
@genus_counts = Table.count(:all, :conditions=> {:col1 => params[:gm], :col3 != nil :col2 => nil})
```

It's not recognising "!=" operator.... Kindly suggest me and correct above statement. I am in doubt to apply it as array value.

`@genus_counts` is a local variable, I can't apply it as array. Kindly tell me the suggestion to bring this output to view.erb.html

-- 
With Regards
Palani Kannan. K

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do something like (as answered before)(inside your controller) :

```
@genus_count = Table.count(:all, :conditions => ['col3 is not null and col2 is null and col1 = ?', params[:gm])
```

then `@genus_count` will contain the count you want. Since `@genus_count` is an instance variable of your controller, you can just refer to it inside your view like this:

```
The wanted count = <%= @genus_count %>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

as in

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

you can use something similar to this form instead:

```
"orders_count = ? AND locked = ?", params[:orders], false
```

so you can use

```
"   ... col3 IS NOT null ... "
```

Comment: 'true' and 'false' give output without error. But, @genus_counts not produces results to html.erb. May be stored in $genus_count... then how I can get this variable to html.erb? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The hash format of specifying conditions such as `:conditions=> {:col1 => params[:gm], :col2 => nil}` can only be used to specify conditions that are all `=` joined with `AND`.

It's nice to read so use that format when applicable, but when you need an `OR`, or a comparator other than `=`, you'll need to use a slightly different format:

`:conditions => ["col1 = ? AND col3 != ? AND col2 = ?", params[:gm], nil, nil]`

This format takes an array, the first element of which is an sql fragment, and the remaining parameters are sql sanitized (preventing sql injection attack, and converting nil to 'NULL' etc) and inserted into the sql fragment replacing the `?` (in order of appearance).